# Emacs, change of $PWD variable

Tags: bash, emacs, pwd

I do always work with emacs in no windows mode (emacs -nw) inside Guake, and I have set guake to open a new tab in the same directory on which I'm in that moment.

My purpose is:

- If I work with a certain file in emacs, and I open a new tab, I want the path (`PWD variable`) is the same of the file.
- When I close emacs, the PWD variable is restored with its original value.

How can I set my `.emacs` file to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of  wvxvw's answer:

`(defvar pwd-orig (getenv "PWD"))`

`(add-hook 'find-file-hook 
          (lambda () (setenv "PWD" default-directory)))`

`(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook (lambda () (setenv "PWD" pwd-orig)))`

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`cd`
You can use it in `.emacs` like this:

```
(defvar initial-directory (getenv "PWD"))
(cd "~/some-directory/")
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook (lambda () (cd initial-directory)))
```

Sorry, I didn't test the above, but it looks like it would work. (Not sure about how many arguments the `'kill-emacs-hook` takes.

Comment: I search something automatic. Each time I open a file, or I change to a buffer with any file opened, I've PWD changed.