# change directory in osx terminal.app from emacs -nw

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal

Suppose I launch `emacs -nw` from `DIRECTORY_A` in Terminal.app (osx 10.9.5). Then, inside emacs I navigate to `DIRECTORY_B` (e.g., using dired). At this point, if I close emacs (`C-x C-c`) or if I do `M-x suspend-frame` I find myself in `DIRECTORY_A` (of course this is standard behavior).

I would like to be able to execute a command from within emacss that changes `DIRECTORY_A` (the directory from which I invoked `emacs -nw`) to `DIRECTORY_B` (the current directory in emacs). So that when I exit emacs I would end-up in `DIRECTORY_B`.

I (naively) attempted achieving this by using a shell command:

```
(defun my-cd-to-current-dir ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat "cd " (expand-file-name "."))))
```

In the `*Messages*` buffer I can see

```
(Shell command succeeded with no output)
```

but when I exit emacs I am still in `DIRECTORY_A`.

Clarification:
When I change directory within emacs, the value of the environmental variable PWD (accessed via `M-! env`) reflects correctly the current directory (`DIRECTORY_B`). But if I do `M-x suspend-frame` and then issue `env` from the prompt in the terminal I get `DIRECTORY_A`. Hence, changing the value of PWD from within emacs doesn't seem to solve the problem (it is possible that I am doing something wrong).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs, change of $PWD variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123765/emacs-change-of-pwd-variable)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think that this resolves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, currently I am using

```
(defun my-open-terminal-in-current-dir ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat "open -b com.apple.terminal " (expand-file-name "."))))
```

to open a new terminal application in the current directory. Unfortunately, this is not very convenient so I would appreciate any ideas on how to solve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a another solution.

```
;; thx http://superuser.com/questions/466619/open-new-terminal-tab-and-execute-script
;; thx http://qiita.com/ganmacs/items/cfc5f9c2213a6a9e6579

(defun cd-on-terminal (&optional command)
  "Change directory to current buffer path by Terminal.app.  COMMAND is execute after cd."
  (interactive)
  (util/execute-on-terminal
   (concat (format "cd %s" default-directory) command)))

(defun util/execute-on-terminal (command)
  "Change directory to current buffer path by Terminal.app.  COMMAND."
  (interactive "MCommand: ")
  (do-applescript
   (format "tell application \"Terminal\"
activate
tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"t\" using command down
repeat while contents of selected tab of window 1 starts with linefeed
delay 0.01
end repeat
do script \"%s\" in window 1
end tell"
           command)))
```